# how can i run url and save loaded file again without opening browsers?

Tags: c#, winforms, url, browser, download

I have a text file with list of words and i have generated list of URLs with these word:

> ```
> word1
> word2
> word3
> .
> .
>
> http://www.example.com/word1
> http://www.example.com/word2
> http://www.example.com/word3
> ```

i see these code to run URLs,  but these open browsers or media player ones:

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(URL);
```

or...

```
 WebBrowser1.Navigate(URL);
```

i want to run these URLs and save again files that are loaded with name "word1.mp3,word2.mp3,..."  without opening browser or saving files one by one.
how can i do that in windows form with c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `System.net` namespace and `WebClient` class to access internet pages from C#:

```
WebClient cl = new WebClient();
cl.DownloadFile(url, fileSaveAddress); //download the file
```

and the better way to download a file is using `async` methods:

```
    cl.DownloadFileAsync(URI, fileSaveAddress);
```

It will download the file asynchronously and will not hang the UI.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877741/access-to-the-path-is-denied it'll help you

Answer (score 1):

Following code snippet save HTML string of the specified URL without opening it.
Alter it according to your scenario(client.DownloadFile).

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
    string content = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com");
```