# C# with Google Apis Authentication Error : Access to the path ' Google.Apis.Auth ' denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, youtube-api

Hi i am trying to upload vidoe on youtube using v3 api and C#. and i am getting error "Access to the path ' Google.Apis.Auth ' denied"

below is my code

```
var client_secretspath = Server.MapPath("/App_Data/client_secrets.json");
                using (var stream = new FileStream(client_secretspath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, 
                        new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None
                    );
                }
```

This code is working properly on local but when i try to upload on server it is not working.
I set full permission on IIS. also check to change physical position of json file but still getting this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to the path is denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877741/access-to-the-path-is-denied)

Comment: i already set full permission

Comment: Have you tried supplying the full path I always do.  "c:\App_Data\client_secrets.json"

Comment: yes i tried but still not success