# Why Access path denied?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read a text file with File.ReadAllText and FileStream, but for some reason I get the System.UnauthorizedAccessException every time.

```
 class consultas
{
    public consultas()
    {


    }

    private string Inativos = @"C:\Users\Mathias Cruz\Desktop\helloWorld\helloWorld\Consultas";

    public string getInativos()
    {
        try
        {
            // string path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            this.Inativos = File.ReadAllText(this.Inativos);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;


        }
        return this.Inativos;


    }
}
```

Why? I have permissions in that folder, so why do I get this exception?

Comment: Give this post a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877741/access-to-the-path-is-denied

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your code, you are either trying to read a Folder since you didn't specify a extension on your File Path here:

```
private string Inativos = @"C:\Users\Mathias Cruz\Desktop\helloWorld\helloWorld\Consultas";
```

It will definitely throw a UnauthorizedAccessException error. So make sure you have the exact file path together with its extension.

Comment: Thanks man, i forget this detail kkkkkkkk thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Because the path is a *directory*.
Please check your file address.
This method needs a **file address**.
Here is a sample code:

```
File.ReadAllText("C:\\yourfile.txt");
```