# How to access the path?

Tags: c#, image, model-view-controller, routes, access-denied

I want to store the image in a folder. For that, i give path of folder as "D:\Project\Site\ImageFiles". By using this path, I stored the image in the folder successfully.

Now I want to store the image by giving path as "..\Project\Site\ImageFiles".

Here is the code:

```
 public static bool SaveOriginalImage(string imageName, Image image)
    {
        try
        {
            var imageLocation = "D:\Project\Site\ImageFiles\";
            if (!Directory.Exists(imageLocation))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(imageLocation);
            }

            imageLocation = imageLocation + imageName;
            var bitMapImage = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
            bitMapImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);
            using (var graphicImageContent = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapImage))
            {
                graphicImageContent.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                graphicImageContent.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphicImageContent.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphicImageContent.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height);
            }

            bitMapImage.Save(imageLocation);
            bitMapImage.Dispose();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

When giving path as "..\Project\Site\ImageFiles\", i get exception "Access is denied for the path ..\Project\Site\ImageFiles\ " when creating directory.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Two possibilities: Start your application with more access right (e.g. as administrator) or set access permissions to the path for the user that starts the application

Comment: @ Romano Zumbé, I cannot able to understand your answer. Can you tell once again.

Comment: Please check this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877741/access-to-the-path-is-denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877741/access-to-the-path-is-denied)

Comment: I think the problem is, that you really don't have the right to access the folder. Start the application as administrator (right click "start as Administrator") then try again

Answer (score 0):

```
var fullPath = Path.GetFullPath("..\Project\Site\ImageFiles")
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx