# Could not add Newtonsoft.Json on Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm trying to add the `Newtonsoft.Json` package but I get this error:

> All packages and projects are compatible with net6.0.
>
> Access to the path '--' is denied.
>
> Permission denied

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 for Mac.

I tried to search for other ways to install the package but it failed.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Are you doing this from the command line? If so, I'd suggest you to add the command that you're running, to see if the problem is there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access to the path is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877741/access-to-the-path-is-denied)

Answer (score 0):

Look like you not have permission. Please run the Visual Studio as Administrator  or give proper permission to user under which Visual Studio is running.